# Reacting to focusNode events in a stateless widget

Tags: flutter

#### Setup:

1 parent stateful widget
1 child stateless widget with a textfield


Upon a tap event in the parent, I'm attempting to trigger a `focusNode.unfocus();` on the focusNode in the child widget.


Here's my current (failed) attempt - where the idea is to pass the focusnode to the child in hopes the unfocus() gets fired within the child widget. This is not happening and I would appreciate any input on how to approach this problem.

Thanks in advance

```
class Child extends StatelessWidget {
  Child({Key key, this.focusNode}) : super(key: key);

  final FocusNode focusNode;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      focusNode: focusNode
    );
  }
}


class ParentState extends State<Parent> {
  FocusNode focusNode;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    focusNode.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Child(this.focusNode),
        Button(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() { this.focusNode.unfocus(); });
          }
        )
      ]
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What about `unfocus` inside `setState` method?

Comment: @BambinoUA That was definitely missing, but no success yet. Updating question to include setState()

Comment: @TomNijs I don't see any error so far, and even you don't need setState. Would you mind to show more code? If you do like to share, there is another way, try `FocusScope.of(context).focusedChild?.unfocus();`

Comment: @SamChan I posted an answer below. The issue (which I omitted from my code for brevity) came from something else. After some debugging I found out the issue came from a google maps integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above solution was correct, I had omitted the part where the unfocus was being triggered by an onTap on a GestureDetector wrapped around a GoogleMaps widget which does not work.